# How to receive some files at A node.js/express server and send files to B node.js/express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, express, server-to-server

I'm working on node.js express servers
I'm stuck! Cant find the correct answer in documentation or somewhere else.

I need be able to:

1. receive 2-3 PDF files at server **A** from client-side
2. upload those files to server **B**
3. make ZIP file from files on **B** server and save it to S3 bucket
4. respond to server **A** with a link to ZIP file
5. Save to DB at server **A**

All stages are not a problem for me except **2**.
Please help me.

How to upload files from req.files to another server with modules such as `request` or `HTTP` or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular difference from receiving files from the client on the server A and receiving files from server A on the server B. The code should be almost the same. So the only tricky part is sending files from A to B and it is covered quite well by the [request.js documentation](https://github.com/mikeal/request), especially its section "Streaming".

BTW, your question is not quite well match the rules of this site. See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the details.

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.